# What does "12345" + 2 do in C?

Tags: c

I've seen *this* done in C before:

```
#define MY_STRING "12345"
...
#define SOMETHING (MY_STRING + 2)
```

What does SOMETHING get expanded to, here? Is this even legal? Or do they mean this?:

```
#define SOMETHING (MY_STRING[2])
```

Comment: So what you don't have a compiler?

Comment: Sometimes asking Stack Overflow is quicker than trying it out on a compiler...

Comment: Quicker?  http://codepad.org/VRZvcphU  Took me all of 60 seconds...

Comment: @Rook - It's one thing to compile it and see what it does, it's another thing to _understand_ it.

Comment: @bta - it took you 60 seconds to compile and run some code, and see the output. The OP's goal was to go from not knowing what a certain kind of syntax means, to knowing what it means. You didn't accomplish that in 60 seconds. For some expressions the meaning is easily inferable from a given test case, at least for that test case, but for many test cases you'll get syntax errors, or no discernable effect, or an incomprehensible effect, or a misleading effect. Anyone who tries to learn the syntax and semantics of a complex programming language solely by trial and error is delusional.

Comment: @LarsH: I agree.  That's why my statement was a comment and not an answer.  I was merely responding to Joe's comment (even though I now see that I didn't mark my comment as a reply...)

Comment: I do wonder if LarsH actually bothered to read Joe's comment that bta responded to before launching into that rant.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

String literals exist in the fixed data segment of the program, so they appear to the compiler as a type of pointer.

```
+-+-+-+-+-+--+
|1|2|3|4|5|\0|
+-+-+-+-+-+--+
 ^ MY_STRING
     ^ MY_STRING + 2
```

Comment: I too love ASCII art, so I have to vote this one as the answer.

Comment: so this one win for the ASCII art... ;)

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: Yes, the same will go for Unicode. The L"StringLiteral" will have `const wchar_t*` type, so `+` will advance by the number of `wchar_t` s.

Comment: Men are visual creatures; if it looks good, then it must be right.

Answer (score 20):

When you have an array or pointer, `p+x` is equivalent to `&p[x]`. So `MY_STRING + 2` is equivalent to `&MY_STRING[2]`: it yields the address of the third character in the string.

Notice what happens when you add 0. `MY_STRING + 0` is the same as `&MY_STRING[0]`, both of which are the same as writing simply `MY_STRING` since a string reference is nothing more than a pointer to the first character in the string. Happily, then, the identity operation "add 0" is a no-op. Consider this a sort of mental unit test we can use to check that our idea about what `+` means is correct.

Comment: I think my hangup here was that I didn't know that a quoted string was equal to the character array, at least syntax-wise. Thanks. +1.